# Reporting an ambiguous driving record case on my medical application

Tags: medical

I am filling out my renewal application for a third-class medical.  It asks about my driving record, and about 15 years ago I was living in California with a valid driver license from another state and using that to drive, and since I had lived in California for more than 30 days without getting a California license, I was going to be accused of driving without a license (after a traffic stop for an expired registration).  I got a letter from the district attorney saying that since I was a first-time offender I could do a "character improvement program" which was a workbook that some company mailed to me, and I did the workbook and paid the $300 fee and that was the end of it.  I am looking at my California driving record and I do not see anything at all about that on my driving record.  Do I need to report this on my medical application, even if there is no mention of it on my driving record?  Another thing is that I forgot to report it on my last application, and apparently my driving record was good enough because they issued me a medical certificate.  If I mention it this time, they may wonder why I didn't report it last time.

Comment: You should talk to AOPA's pilot protection group.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the thing to do.  Thanks.

Comment: I honestly don't recall seeing any questions about driving records on a medical application.  (and I have had 2nd and 1st class medicals)  Is this really a thing with the FAA?  In any case, it is an administrative issue, not a moving violation like a DUI.  It is about as applicable to your medical health for flying as paying your phone bill 3 days late is relevant to a doctor's clearance to play sports.